# Does servlet not have any extensions?

Tags: java, servlets

I like to know like whenever user requests a jsp page we write hello.jsp or any html file we write hello.html or any image hello.jpeg.
My question is does servlet not have any extension ? Is it called directly called by name?

Comment: You've asked 7 java-related questions in 2 days, and accepted none of them. How about clearing your backlog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Servlets, you have to explicitly tell the Servlet Container what URLs (either specific URLs or wildcards) map to what servlet. For example:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The above example would map the URL `/hello` to the servlet `com.example.HelloWorld`.

You can also do some wildcard mapping. For example:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This would map requests ending in "`.html`" to the HelloWorld servlet. But you aren't limited to any particular extensions. You could use anything you want:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorld</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.foo</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

All of this configuration takes place in your web application's `web.xml` file.

Comment: +1. Maybe also mention that in addition to extensions, you can also register path prefixes.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have it fully in your own hands. It's not necessarily called by its name, it's called by its `url-pattern`. You can name it to whatever you want, e.g. `/pages/*` will run the servlet whenever you call `http://example.com/pages/foo.jsp` or `http://example.com/pages/foo` (which in turn gives the pathinfo back by `request.getPathInfo()`, so that you can determine what action to take and/or where to forward the request to). Or `*.page` which runs the servlet whenever you call `http://example.com/foo.page` (which in turn gives URI back by `request.getRequestURI()`).

To preprocess requests (when one requests a page for view) you normally use `doGet()` method. To postprocess requests (after a POST form submit), you normally use `doPost()` method.

You can in fact create as many servlets as you want, e.g. `RegisterServlet` listening on `/register` which is backed by a `register.jsp` as view and a `LoginServlet` listening on `/login` and backed by a `login.jsp` as view, etcetera. You can hide JSPs from direct access by placing them in `/WEB-INF` so that users are forced to call them through the servlet.

In MVC world, there's usually means of only **one** servlet listening on a certain `url-pattern`, which is called the *Front Controller*. In Sun JSF for example, there's the `FacesServlet` which runs whenever an URL matching by default `*.jsf` or `/faces/*` is called. In Apache Struts for example, there's the `ActionServlet` which listens on by default `*.do`. They determines which action to take and/or which view (the JSP file) to display based on the URL, request parameters and/or mappings. You're however free to change those default `url-pattern`s. You can even change the default `url-pattern` of the `JspServlet` in servlercontainer's `web.xml`, which by default listens on `*.jsp`. It's however recommended to stick to a sensible and standardized`url-pattern`.

It might be interesting to know that any other "undefinied" URL patterns are covered by a "default" servlet. Check the servletcontainer's `web.xml`, you'll see one servlet which listens on `/` and thus in fact serves *everything*. It also manages display of directoy listings. In Tomcat for example it's called the `DefaultServlet` and described [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/default-servlet.html).